# SQL pull Multiple dates from a long text field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out a way to pull multiple date entries from a text column so I can filter them later on.

Please take a look at the attached image.

There could be hundreds of these mini notes entered into the overall text column and I will have to figure out how I can identify each date and set it as a new column also. So if one text field has 100 dates, ill need 100 dynamically created columns to filter by. And if the next rows text field only has 2 dates, ill need it to dynamically create 2 columns for that row.

IS something like this possible?

Unfortunately this is how the software we are using is set up and those mini note dates are not saved as a date time anywhere else in the DB which would make this 10 times easier....

I have done something very similar with this query....

```
SELECT TOP (500) 'Referral', COUNT(cn.Note_ID),cn.Note_DateOccurred,vp.Person_Name,ltrim(replace(replace(replace(replace(substring(replace(replace(replace(cast(Note_SummaryRTF as nvarchar(MAX)), '{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deftab720{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset1 MS Sans Serif;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;}\plain\f0\fs24\cf0 \plain\f0\fs24\cf0\b ', ''),
        '\plain\f0\fs20\cf0', ''),
           '\par', '\n'), CHARINDEX('Completed by:', replace(replace(replace(cast(Note_SummaryRTF as nvarchar(MAX)), '{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deftab720{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset1 MS Sans Serif;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;}\plain\f0\fs24\cf0 \plain\f0\fs24\cf0\b ', ''),
        '\plain\f0\fs20\cf0', ''),
           '\par', '\n')),50),'\n',''),'}', ''), 'Completed By:', ''), '\''a0', '')) a
FROM CHRT_Note cn
JOIN CHRT_OtherNote con on cn.Note_ID = con.Note_ID
JOIN View_Patient vp on con.Patient_ID = vp.Patient_ID
WHERE cn.Note_DateOccurred > '1/31/2018'
and Note_RTF like '%Referral Completed By:%' 
GROUP BY cast(Note_SummaryRTF as 
nvarchar(MAX)),cn.Note_DateOccurred,vp.Person_Name
```

Comment: You could use `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` to get the date part of the string and then parse it into a date. Can you show the sql you have tried so far. Also which SQL DB you are using.

Comment: I would use a regular expression, but you do need to provide sample data we can copy, not a screen shot, and as @VidmantasBlazevicius said, an example of what you have tried and the database type.

Comment: This is SQL Server (T-SQL)..

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I have done something very simular like this query,

Comment: @adv Had you provided sample data that can be copied and pasted, i am sure somebody would have helped you out with a regular expression or another approach already.

Comment: @avd This data looks like it could be sensitive in nature (i.e. HIPAA data). If it is real data I would suggest you delete the screenshot and re-post de-identified data.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Actually your comment was all the help i needed. I was able to figure it out with Charindex and Substring...

Comment: @avd You're very much welcome, I posted it as answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING to get the date part of the string and then parse it into a date.

Answer (score 0):

> So if one text field has 100 dates, ill need 100 dynamically created
> columns to filter by. And if the next rows text field only has 2
> dates, ill need it to dynamically create 2 columns for that row.
>
> IS something like this possible?

Not as you describe. Rows in a table cannot have different number of columns, but you could identify the maximum number of columns you'll need and use that.

If you're doing a lot of text manipulation you might benefit from processing data in application code - text extract, formatting, parsing etc are far simpler in application leveraging text frameworks than they are in a relational database.

In the event that you can't take the data out of the database, this seems like a perfect opportunity to utilize the much maligned .NET integration capability of SQL Server, aka. [SQL CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration) (I've maligned it myself). It's a uniquely shaped hammer that people use to hit all manner of nails, but this particular case (manipulating text inside the database) might be well suited.